# Solution For Date Format In Parameterizes Sql Query In 'DD/MM/YYYY' Format

Tags: c#

I have asked this question in many sites and my question remain unanswered. Some people advise me to use datetimepicker against maskedtextbox.

It is true that datetimepicker solved the all kind date related problem, whereas masked textbox return a string and that's why it's create a datetime conversion problem in parameterized sql query in C#.

In most case we are not utilise datetimepicker due to time consuming issue. I mean if there is thousand of data entry pending and if we use datetimepicker then over finger are divided between mouse and keyboard. Hence in my case I always use maskedtextbox and it creates a problem of date conversion. I have tried to solve it in the following way:

```
String sql="insertintodummy(name,date)values(@name,convert(datetime,'"+maskedTextBox1.text+"', 103)"; //  for 'dd/mm/yyyy' format.
sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand(sql,con);
cmd.parameters.Add("@name",SqldbType.Varchar).Value= textbox1.text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I think there is no way to utilise the above datetime conversion in a parameterized query with C#, VS-2005.

The above code is useful in case of only datefield must enter way. If there is better way than please suggest.

Now it is perfect Solution here below.

```
string sql="insert into dummy(name,date)values(@name,@date)";

IFormateprovider Culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR",True);

DateTime mydate=DateTime.parse(
maskedtextbox1.text,Culture,DateTimeStyles.NocurrentDateDefault
);

sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand(sql,con);

cmd.Parameters.Add(@name,SqlDbtypes.Varchar).Values= Textbox1.text;

cmd.Parameters.Add(@date, SqlDbtypes.Datetime).Values=mydate;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `DateTime enterDate = new DateTime(maskedTextBox1.Text);`?

Comment: @lazarus sir, it's through compiling error like 'string long'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do the conversion in Sql, (**and risk injection by only partially parameterising your query**) when there's a perfectly good parameter with `SqlDbType.DateTime` just begging to be used:

```
string sql = "insert into dummy (name, date) values (@name, @date)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqldbType.Varchar).Value = textbox1.text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(maskedTextBox1.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Obvious caveats:

- No check that maskedTextBox1.Text actually contains a DateTime (`DateTime.TryParse`)
- No check that the provided DateTime falls in the range of DateTime's that SqlDbType.DateTime handles

Comment: +1. The string should definitely be converted before it's sent to the database. The DateTime.ParseExact and DateTime.TryParseExact methods would give you better control over how the date is converted from the string.

Comment: @Rob, Sir ur code is seems to put exact date format order as sql have. i mean sql date format is mm/dd/yyyy format and u enter in dd/mm/yyyy format than it's gives an error.

Comment: @Guffa Sir, I have already try it as per ur suggestion but sir am failed to convert it. sir i am using c#, vs-2005 and no solution i have found on it. if u provide it then sir ur welcome. please help me.

Comment: @mahesh: The date format that the SQL Server uses is irrelevant as the date is parsed in the C# code, so it's the default date format of the computer that is used. You can use `DateTime.ParseExact(textbox1.text, "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` to parse the string.

Comment: @Guffa sir, the IFromatProvider you provide it is not available in vs-2005, c#  I mean CultureInfo.InvariantCulture

Comment: I mean with ur whole code the IFormateProvider is suggested is not available in software. may be some coding mistake or else.

Comment: @Guffa sir, or something missing on it.

Comment: @mahesh, according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx the `DateTime.ParseExact` method is available as far back as .net 1.0, you may want to see if that linked page answers your question.

Comment: @Rob Sir, thank you very much Sir for ur suggestion it may be work but one curiocity in my mind. Sir please be not feel bad. but i am trying to tell u sir it is very instresting and useful example gaves by msdn. my wish sir first u have to try it in your VS-2005 C# Program. and then we will discuss it. sir i have face very strange problem with it. I think it's solution with u. so Sir for my sake please help me and try it on your C#, VS-2005. Please Sir.

Comment: @Rob Sir, Thank You very much sir it is solved with your kind help. am accept ur answer. There is lot's good things in this community to must have to learn for me. I am proud to be part of this community. One Final Question Sir I have to edit this code due to enable better for learn to our new commer can i do it Sir, If Yes than How?

Comment: @Guffa Sir, Thanks once again.

Comment: @mahesh: The `CultureInfo` class has always been there, but it's in the `Globalisation` namespace, so you may need to add `using System.Globalization;` at the top of the file.

Comment: @Guffa Sir, i am heartly apolozige for that. I forgot to reply it that sir i have tested ur code and found that it's return very strange value. e.g. if  i have type in dd/mm/yyyy format like '31/03/2010' it's return '01/31/2010' with time. I don't know what's wrong with it. please sir solve it for my knowledge it's important for me.

Comment: @mahesh: Are you sure that the date changes from 03 to 01? Otherwise the result looks perfectly all right. The result is a DateTime value, so it always has a time component, but it doesn't have a format. So, depending on how you view the result the format may differ, but when you send it in the database it's just a point in time without any formatting issues. You are viewing the result in a way that it gets formatted with brittish style rather than US style, but if it displays as '03/31/3010' it's clearly the correct value.

Comment: @Guffa Sir, I am 100% sure about it. as because i have tried it four days before with this IFormatProvider but it's differ from ur code. but it's similar to ur code in way of parse/tryparse it's also return same value which I have suggested. Now sir it is important for me to find solution of it. Ok sir do u have try it. what's a value return it. please sir look into this matters.

Comment: @mahesh: Yes, I did try it before answering the last time, and it does return a DateTime value that when I display it shows `2010-03-31 00:00:00`. So, there has to be something in your code that you are doing differently. For example, if you use `mm` instead of `MM` in the format string, it would parse minutes instead of months and then the month component would get the default value of 1, giving the result `2010-01-31 00:03:00`.

Comment: @Guffa Sir, am talking about sql-2000. I have checked it and found the value '01/03/2010' is in database. with time.

Comment: The datebase just shows you the value that you sent to it, it's in the C# where you create the value that it get's wrong.

Comment: @Guffa, Oh! yes Sir ur write it was the big mistake. sir i am agree with u. How can I accept ur answer.

Comment: @Guffa, Sorry Sir for replying delay due to Lord Ganesha's Festival In India. it was the time of praying.

Comment: @Guffa Sir ur not replying that how can i accept ur answer lots thx.

Comment: @Guffa, OK Sir but it is great help Sir,